# How to hardcode the unsubscribe /optout URL in a transactional email?

Tags: email, civirules

I would like to send a transactional email with unsubscribe/opt-out url included. It usually gets triggered by civirules when the person gets added to a group. when email is sent the unsubscribe url does not render. civirules have suggested I hardcode the link. I have tried `https://example.com/civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe?reset=1&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}`
But with this link I get "Missing Parameters" errors. What is missing here? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the unsubscribe link either needs mailing id or group id. The other option would be to create a profile with groups and opt-out field. And the include the profile as a unsubscribe link

```
https://example.com/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=2&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}
```

Where gid is a profile id.

Cheers

Pradeep